# Setting up Guard with Minitest in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, guard, minitest

I'm having problems getting Guard to run in my Rails 3.2 project. My test folder looks like the default rails test structure:

```
▾ test/
  ▾ fixtures/
      customers.yml
  ▾ functional/
  ▾ integration/
  ▾ performance/
      browsing_test.rb
  ▾ unit/
      customer_test.rb
    test_helper.rb
```

and my Guardfile looks like this:

```
guard 'minitest' do
  # with Minitest::Unit
  watch(%r|^test/(.*)\/?test_(.*)\.rb|)
  watch(%r|^lib/(.*)([^/]+)\.rb|)     { |m| "test/#{m[1]}test_#{m[2]}.rb" }
  watch(%r|^test/test_helper\.rb|)    { "test" }

  # with Minitest::Spec
   watch(%r|^spec/(.*)_spec\.rb|)
   watch(%r|^lib/(.*)([^/]+)\.rb|)     { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
   watch(%r|^spec/spec_helper\.rb|)    { "spec" }

  # Rails 3.2
  watch(%r|^app/controllers/(.*)\.rb|) { |m| "test/controllers/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r|^app/helpers/(.*)\.rb|)     { |m| "test/helpers/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r|^app/models/(.*)\.rb|)      { |m| "test/unit/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }  

  # Rails
  # watch(%r|^app/controllers/(.*)\.rb|) { |m| "test/functional/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  # watch(%r|^app/helpers/(.*)\.rb|)     { |m| "test/helpers/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  # watch(%r|^app/models/(.*)\.rb|)      { |m| "test/unit/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }  
end
```

but upon running guard, it just says it's watching, but doesn't actually run any of the tests in customer_test.rb, even when I explicitly ask it to run the minitests. If I run the tests from the command-line with `ruby -Itest test/unit/customer_test.rb`, they operate as expected. I know I'm doing something wrong in the Guardfile config, but just what is it?

Comment: You do know Guard is just watching for file changes? It doesn't run anything unless a file changes. Edit one of your test files and save it and it should run it.

Comment: @Casper yes, but my understanding is that it should run all tests it finds on start-up, and that if I explicitly run 'minitest' in the guard prompt it should also run all tests, and at present it isn't doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `run_all_on_start` feature, this is currently part of the [Unreleased features for the v1.0.0](https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#unreleased-changes). Hopefully, a new beta will be released soon. In the meantime you can try guard-minitest from master with:

```
gem 'guard-minitest', github: 'guard/guard-minitest'
```

Please report any issues to the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/guard/guard-minitest/issues/new) after trying the master branch, thanks!